# Get the current date and time in PHP with '2016-07-04 00:00:00.000' format

Tags: php, datetime

I am using mssql db with php. Which PHP function can return the current datetime. (i.e.) I want the current date and time to be saved in the following format say for example,

```
2016-07-04 11:10:05.000
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `echo substr(date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", time()),0,-3);`

Comment: @Thamilan, nope i didnt get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use date->format   http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php

> ```
> $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
> echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
> ```

Comment: echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); is enough..?

Comment: if you want miilsecond  you need "Y-m-d H:i:s.u" if you want ever 0000 you can use "Y-m-d H:i:s.0000" ... if you want only second "Y-m-d H:i:s" you obtain  2016-07-04 11:10:05

Comment: yes i got it. Thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 1):

With "date" you can format the output and with "time" you get the current unix time.

**Example**

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", time());
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

12-hour format

`date("Y-m-d h:i:s.u")`

24-hour format

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u")`